# How to make a VSCode extension that gets enabled only when an xml with a specific schema is used?

Tags: xml, xsd, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to make an extension with tools for editing xml files that use a specific schema. Is there a way to have right-click menu and autocompletion of tags only when a file with that schema is used?

Answer (score 2):

First, you must define that your extension only works `xml` files, like this:

On your `package.json` change the `onLanguage` to `xml`

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:xml"
]
```

And on the extesions.ts set the `language` of the documentSelector to `xml` too

```
const clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = {
        // Register the server for plain XML documents
        documentSelector: [{ scheme: 'file', language: 'xml' }],
    };
```

Doing so, all your commands will be visible for any XML file, whether has your schema or not. If you don't want this, you should take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10401), which in the comments, says how you can *hide* commands based on *context*. In your case, you would define this context based on the schema.